# Grouping sorted coordinates based on proximity to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, clustering

I created an algotrithm that groups a *sorted* `list` of coordinates into buckets based on their proximity (30) to one another.

Steps:

1. Create a new key with a list value and pop the first point in the list into it
2. Scan the list of points for points that are close to it. Push matches to the new list and replace values with `None`
3. After scan, filter the list, removing `None` values
4. Back to one, until `points` is empty.

I can't modify the list by deleting elements because I use indexes.

After I'm done grouping, I take the average of each group of points.

```py
def group_points(points):
    groups = {}
    groupnum = 0
    while len(points) > 1:
        groupnum += 1
        key = str(groupnum)
        groups[key] = []
        ref = points.pop(0)
        for i, point in enumerate(points):
            d = get_distance(ref, point)
            if d < 30:
                groups[key].append(points[i])
                points[i] = None
        points = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, points))
    # perform average operation on each group
    return list([[int(np.mean(list([x[0] for x in groups[arr]]))), int(np.mean(list([x[1] for x in groups[arr]])))] for arr in groups])


def get_distance(ref, point):
    # print('ref: {} , point: {}'.format(ref, point))
    x1, y1 = ref[0], ref[1]
    x2, y2 = point[0], point[1]
    return math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

If possible, I would like to reduce the amount of variables and total loops over the points array. Do I need to use indexes? Is it possible to achieve this in one pass over `points`?

Comment: How many points do you expect to process? Do the points have any special properties or distribution?

Comment: "a sorted `list`" - sorted according to what criterium?

Comment: They are sorted by the x value then the y value. The number of points varies, but its almost guaranteed they will all fit in some sort of group with at least one other point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General comments:

You are basically using the `groups` dict like a list.  Might as well just use a list.

An empty data structure (list, dict, set, tuple) is False in a boolean context, so `while len(points) > 1:` can be simplified to `while points:`

It is generally slower to pop from the front of a list than the back of a list, because after removing the first item all the rest of the items get moved up one spot.

`points.pop()` actually changes the list passed in.  Make sure that's what you want.

`filter(None, points)` filters out all "False" items.

`[ ... ]` creates a list.  So, `list( [ ... ] )` is redundant.

You can just use `x1, y1 = ref`.

Put that all together and you get something like:

```
def group_points(points):
    groups = []
    while points:
        far_points = []
        ref = points.pop()
        groups.append([ref])
        for point in points:
            d = get_distance(ref, point)
            if d < 30:
                groups[-1].append(point)
            else:
                far_points.append(point)

        points = far_points

    # perform average operation on each group
    return [list(np.mean(x, axis=1).astype(int)) for x in groups]

def get_distance(ref, point):
    # print('ref: {} , point: {}'.format(ref, point))
    x1, y1 = ref
    x2, y2 = point
    return math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

You also might want to look at functions in `scipy.cluster`.

Comment: `return [list(np.mean(x, axis=1).astype(int)) for x in groups]` 

Will this work if each element is an array? `[x,y]`

Comment: Also, are lists faster than dicts?

Comment: @Josh Sharkey, yes `np.mean()` works on arrays.  The axis parameter tells it how to do the calculation.  Without `axis` is takes the mean of the whole array.  And yes, lists can be faster than dicts and likely use less memory.  Like many things in programming there is a tradeoff.  In most cases code that is easier to understand is worth the slight performance tradeoff.

Comment: so `np.mean(axis=1)` will average the x values and the y values separately and return a single list `[x_avg, y_avg]`?

Comment: @Josh yes. np.mean(array) returns the mean of the whole array. with axis=0 it returns the mean for each row.  with axis=1 it returns the mean of each column.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while len(points) > 1:
> ```

Shouldn't it be:

```
while len(points) > 0:
```

or else the last point "hangs" unhandled in the points list when finished.

---

> ```
>     ...
>     groups[key] = []
>     ref = points.pop(0)
>     ...
> ```

Don't you forget to insert the `ref` point itself into the new list?:

```
     ...
     ref = points.pop(0)
     groups[key] = [ ref ]         
     ...
```

---

> `if d < 30:`

I would have this distance (`30`) as a parameter of the function:

```
def group_points(points, distance):
```

in order to make it more useful.

---

> ```
> for i, point in enumerate(points):
>     d = get_distance(ref, point)
>     if d < distance:
>         groups[key].append(points[i])
>         points[i] = None
> points = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, points))
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
for point in points:
    if get_distance(ref, point) < distance:
        groups[key].append(point)
points = list(filter(lambda x: x not in groups[key], points))
```

But as eric.m notices in his comment, the original may be more efficient than my suggestion.

---

> ```
> return list([[int(np.mean(list([x[0] for x in groups[arr]]))), int(np.mean(list([x[1] for x in groups[arr]])))] for arr in groups])
> ```

A rather scary statement. Split it up in meaningful parts:

```
def points_mean(points):
  return list(np.mean(points, axis = 0).astype(int))
```

and then

```
return map(points_mean, groups)
```

BtW: Why are you operating in integers and not in floating points?

---

Your method changes the input data set (`points.pop()`), which you as a client normally don't expect. To avoid that, you can do something like:

```
def group_points(points, distance):
    if len(points) == 0 or distance < 0: return []
    groups = [[points[0]]]
    for point in points[1:]:
        handled = False
        for group in groups:
            if get_distance(group[0], point) < distance:
                group.append(point)
                handled = True
                break

        if not handled:
            groups.append([point])

# perform average operation on each group
return map(points_mean, groups)

def points_mean(points):
  return list(np.mean(points, axis = 0).astype(int))

def get_distance(ref, point):
    x1, y1 = ref
    x2, y2 = point
    return math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

---

Disclaimer: I'm not that familiar with Python, so something in the above can maybe be done simpler and more succinct, so regard it as an attempt to think along your lines of thoughts and not as a state of the art.

Comment: Wasn't the `points[i] = None` more efficient? It's faster checking wheter `x is not None` than checking if x is inside a list

Comment: @eric.m: you can have a point there. You could maybe use `points.remove(point)` instead?

Comment: points.remove modifies the list in-place, making it shorter. That screws up the `i` indexing.

Comment: Hold on... where am I? ..this isn't C# :o:o ;-)

Comment: @dfhwze: needed a little change, and it seems that all C#'ers are on vacation :-)

Comment: I get that, I recently started answering Ruby questions myself :s